# How to use pandas to shift the last row to the first

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                         #1                     #2
1980-01-01               11.6985                126.0
1980-01-02               43.6431                134.0
1980-01-03               54.9089                130.0
1980-01-04               63.1225                126.0
1980-01-05               72.4399                120.0
```

What I want to do is to shift the first row of the first column (11.6985) down 1 row, and then the last row of the first column (72.4399) would be shifted to the first row, first column, like so:

```
                         #1                     #2
1980-01-01               72.4399                126.0
1980-01-02               11.6985                134.0
1980-01-03               43.6431                130.0
1980-01-04               54.9089                126.0
1980-01-05               63.1225                120.0
```

The idea is that I want to use these dataframes to find an R^2 value for every shift, so I need to use all the data or it might not work. I have tried to use [pandas.Dataframe.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
print(data)

#Output
1980-01-01               11.6985                126.0
1980-01-02               43.6431                134.0
1980-01-03               54.9089                130.0
1980-01-04               63.1225                126.0
1980-01-05               72.4399                120.0

print(data.shift(1,axis = 0))

1980-01-01                   NaN                  NaN
1980-01-02               11.6985                126.0
1980-01-03               43.6431                134.0
1980-01-04               54.9089                130.0
1980-01-05               63.1225                126.0
```

So it just shifts both columns down and gets rid of the last row of data, which is not what I want.

Any advice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure about the performance, but you could try `numpy.roll`:

```
import numpy as np
print(df.apply(np.roll, shift=1))

#                 #1     #2
#1980-01-01  72.4399  120.0
#1980-01-02  11.6985  126.0
#1980-01-03  43.6431  134.0
#1980-01-04  54.9089  130.0
#1980-01-05  63.1225  126.0
```

---

To shift column `#1` only:

```
df['#1'] = np.roll(df['#1'], shift=1)

print(df)
#                 #1     #2
#1980-01-01  72.4399  126.0
#1980-01-02  11.6985  134.0
#1980-01-03  43.6431  130.0
#1980-01-04  54.9089  126.0
#1980-01-05  63.1225  120.0
```

Comment: This works really well! It shifts both columns, but I think I'll just separate the two columns into separate data-frames and then shift 1 to compare it to the other. Thanks!

Comment: If you only want to roll one column, you can do `df['#1'] = np.roll(df['#1'], shift=1)` for instance.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you could do this with shift, but one way is to use `iloc`:

```
In [11]: res = df.iloc[np.arange(-1, len(df)-1)]

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
                 #1     #2
1980-01-05  72.4399  120.0
1980-01-01  11.6985  126.0
1980-01-02  43.6431  134.0
1980-01-03  54.9089  130.0
1980-01-04  63.1225  126.0

In [13]: res.index = df.index

In [14]: res
Out[14]:
                 #1     #2
1980-01-01  72.4399  120.0
1980-01-02  11.6985  126.0
1980-01-03  43.6431  134.0
1980-01-04  54.9089  130.0
1980-01-05  63.1225  126.0
```

---

If you want this as a new column (just for #1):

```
In [21]: df.iloc[np.arange(-1, len(df)-1), 0]
Out[21]:
1980-01-05    72.4399
1980-01-01    11.6985
1980-01-02    43.6431
1980-01-03    54.9089
1980-01-04    63.1225
Name: #1, dtype: float64

In [22]: df.iloc[np.arange(-1, len(df)-1), 0].values
Out[22]: array([ 72.4399,  11.6985,  43.6431,  54.9089,  63.1225])

In [23]: df["new#1"] = df.iloc[np.arange(-1, len(df)-1), 0].values

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
                 #1     #2    new#1
1980-01-01  11.6985  126.0  72.4399
1980-01-02  43.6431  134.0  11.6985
1980-01-03  54.9089  130.0  43.6431
1980-01-04  63.1225  126.0  54.9089
1980-01-05  72.4399  120.0  63.1225
```

Comment: I suspect there's a small tweak, with the same idea, to make this a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question, but this was my solution, which I believe was a bit neater:

```
df = df.reindex(np.roll(df.index, shift=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new column with the desired ordering and then just sort the rows.

```
df['new_col'] = range(1, len(df)+1)
df['new_col'].loc[len(df)-1] = 0
df['new_col'].loc[0] = len(df)
df = df.reset_index()
```